# Display album art from MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-mediaplayer, albumart, android-cursorloader

I use a CursorLoader in a LoaderManager with a Custom CursorAdapter. I've already achieved to display the Album and the associated Artist, and now I'd like to display the Cover.

Here is my Custom CursorAdapter :

```
public class AlbumsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

     public AlbumsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView albumTitle =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.albumTextView);
        albumTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));

        TextView artistName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.artistTextView);
        artistName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST)));

        ImageView albumCover=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.artistTextView);
        // Here what should I do ?

    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.albums_row,parent,false); 
        return view;
    }   
}
```

I've tried the following without success :

```
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
    File imgFile = new  File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView albumCover=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.album_cover);
        albumCover.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }
```

What does MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART returns and how to use it to ake the ImageView disolay the cover ? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've achieved to load the Albums Covers in the `ImageViews` with :

```
    String coverPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
    Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(coverPath);
    ImageView coverAlbum=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.album_cover);
    coverAlbum.setImageDrawable(img);
```

The problem is that the list is very slow. I guess that I should scale down the resolution of the cover to consume less memory.

Comment: I think using BitMap might improve performace.

Comment: How can i generate bitmaps instead??

Comment: I read this from another SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573972/how-can-i-display-album-art-using-mediastore-audio-albums-album-art - A comment from Ken Wolf suggests using BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String path). I'll be trying that in a second.