# Getting the album cover image from mediastore

Tags: android, mediastore

im using the following code to list all album details including album name, albumid, artistname and album cover image

Following is my code,

```
  public Map<String, String> getAlbumList(Context c) {
        //setup map and cursor
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " !=0";
        final Cursor mCursor = c.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                        MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART,}, selection, null,
                "LOWER ("+MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + ") ASC");

        int count = mCursor.getCount();


        String[] mArtist = new String[count];
        String[] mAlbum = new String[count];
        String[] AlbumID = new String[count];
        String[] imageId = new String[count];

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                mAlbum[i] = mCursor
                        .getString(mCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                mArtist[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));



                AlbumID[i] = Long.toString(mCursor
                        .getLong(mCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)));
                imageId[i] =  mCursor.getString(mCursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART));
                //checking for same previous value
                if(result.containsValue(mAlbum[i])){

                }else{
                    result.put("artist" + j, mArtist[i]);
                    result.put("album" + j, mAlbum[i]);
                    result.put("AlbumID" + j, AlbumID[i]);
                    result.put("AlbumID" + j, imageId[i]);
                    j = j + 1;
                }
                i = i + 1;

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        mCursor.close();
        return result;
    }
```

But im getting the following error message

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: album_art
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT album, artist, album_id, album_art
>   FROM audio WHERE (is_music !=0) ORDER BY LOWER (album) ASC

How can I be able to sort this out?

Im trying to get albumimage with album name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display Album Art using MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM\_ART?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573972/how-can-i-display-album-art-using-mediastore-audio-albums-album-art)

Comment: I have tried using it

Comment: But when im trying to get album art with the album name at the same time, im getting this error.