# Getting bitmap from file path of MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART

Tags: android, bitmap, android-contentprovider, mediastore

```
ContentResolver contentResolver1 = getActivity().getContentResolver();
Uri uri1 = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection1 = new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART};
String selection1 = MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs1 = new String[]{String.valueOf(albumId)};  //albumId is MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID

Cursor cursor1 = contentResolver1.query(uri1, projection1, selection1, selectionArgs1, null);

if (cursor1 != null) {
   if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
       String albumPath = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
       if (albumPath != null)
           albumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(albumPath);          
   }
   cursor1.close();
}
```

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(albumPath)` gives a FileNotFoundException even though `albumPath` has the following value- */storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1502945757087*

The comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17574629) says the same thing about using filepath to get bitmap from BitmapFactory.decodeFile() which isn't working in my case.
How to use the above path to get a bitmap?

Comment: what is your albumPath value? it is null?

Comment: nope. it has a proper path, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: You have to request permission. You don't have to get path. please read it again

The quick one is to lower targetApi to 22 (build.gradle file).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                    new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART}, 
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?", 
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(id_alnum)}, 
                    null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
        //TODO code
    }
```

Comment: same. variable `path` has got a path but `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path)`  gives a file not found exception.

Answer (score -1):

This example uses a string of the full filepath to your albumart

```
     public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String picture, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picture, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picture, options);
}


   public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

some additional example where you use uri's (Source: smoothie by Lucas Rocha):

```
    private Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Uri imageUri, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        is = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   //     e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
    //      e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public Bitmap loadItem(Long id) {
    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri imageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(sArtworkUri, String.valueOf(id));
    Resources res = mContext.getResources();
    int width = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_width);
    int height = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_height);

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(imageUri, width, height);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

for example, looking for albumart for track with id =3, using the uri method:

```
imageUri = content://media/external/audio/albumart/3
sArtworkUri=content://media/external/audio/albumart
```

Comment: can you provide a sample string for the full filepath?

Answer (score -2):

You have to request permission. 
You don't have to get path. 
please read it again

The quick one is to lower targetApi to 22 (build.gradle file).

or using new ask-for-permission model:

[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: How are contacts and mediastore even related?

Comment: you have to check permission. please check it.

Comment: The question isn't about accessing the external storage either. It is about getting a bitmap from a file path.

Comment: This is not an answer, just more confusion for the person asking the question. I will post the answer tomorrow as it is late now in UK