# How to use Picasso for retrieving Album Art from .mp3 file

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, picasso

I'm trying to retrieve Album Art from a single .mp3 file using Picasso but I am unable to do so. Whenever the application starts it shows nothing.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getInit();

    String path = "/root/sdcard/Bom Diggy Diggy.mp3";

    Picasso.with(this).load(new File(path)).into(album_art);
}

public void getInit() {
    album_art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.album_art);
}
```

I also tried using cursor for getting Album Art but it do not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the path of the image in picasso `load()` method, **not** the path of .mp3 file. So for getting the path of album art for any mp3 file you need to use content resolver as following.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART}, 
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?", 
            new String[] {String.valueOf(albumId)}, 
            null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
    Picasso.with(this).load(new File(path)).into(album_art);
}
```

Here, `albumId` refers to `MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID` for that song.

If you're are looking for album art for a particular song (rather than in a list of albums), as far as I know it's a two-stage process since `ALBUM_ART` is a property of `MediaStore.Audio.Albums` and is not available directly as song metadata.

For more information about getting path of album art refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573972/how-can-i-display-album-art-using-mediastore-audio-albums-album-art).

Comment: I tried your code but nothing shows up, do you know any other way? All I want is to get the album art from song and display it on Imageview

Comment: And the link you gave..I read those answer before and nothing works