# How to get some data of songs from MediaStore?

Tags: java, android, mediastore

everyone! I have a project - MusicApp where I need to retrieve all songs from external storage of an android device. I wanna get the next: url, title, artist, icon. How to do it? Now, I have the next code:

```
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
    Cursor cursor =
            getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                String art = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));

                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(art, "drawable", getPackageName());

                mAdapter.addSong(new SongOne(resID, url, name, artist));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
```

And the model

```
 public class SongOne {

    private int img;
    private String url;
    private String title;
    private String artist;

    public SongOne(int img, String url, String title, String artist) {
        this.img = img;
        this.url = url;
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public int getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

}
```

I got the url, title, artist but I've not gotten the icons. How to do it?

Comment: getting an Album art is part of `MediaStore.Audio.Albums`, and not a part of Song's meta data.. if you want the album art of song it is 2 staged process.. Fetch the albumID of song first and get the album art

Comment: @Sam, do you want to tell me that I cant do it in one step and I need to do it through two steps?

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/17574629/8809599

Comment: @Sam, can you implement it in my code? I don't know how to do it (